# Uploaded file can't be accessed

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin

I am trying to upload an image to our S3 service, but aside from the 
seamless execution of the following code, I can't access the file I have uploaded and the file itself isn't on the bucket either.

Another including problem is that I don't have any actual progress response aside from the percentage it has done.

```
private AmazonUploader()
{
    _access = MyKey###";
    _secret = "MySecret###";

    AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config ();
    config.ServiceURL = "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
    config.UseHttp = true;
    config.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;

    _client = new AmazonS3Client (_access, _secret, config);
    _trans = new TransferUtility (_client);
}

public async void UploadImage(string path, string key)
{
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest up = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
    up.BucketName = "myapp/uploads";
    up.FilePath = path;
    up.Key = key;

    up.UploadProgressEvent += up_UploadProgressEvent;
    await _trans.UploadAsync(up);
}

private void up_UploadProgressEvent(object sender, UploadProgressArgs e)
{
    if (e.PercentDone == 100) 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine ("Done uploading");
        if (OnUploadComplete != null) OnUploadComplete ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BucketName seems invalid. Bucketnames cant contain slashes. Maybe you want "uploads" to be part of Key?